# Adding breakpoints changes program behavior

Tags: c++, eclipse, breakpoints

There is a weird issue with some code I'm working with:
As far as I know and as far as I checked there are no components in the code, that rely on anything random, like system time, etc.
Yet it is enough to just add a breakpoint in the code and the behavior of the program changes. It doesn't do anything wrong, it just behaves differently (there are several objects to be selected in the code by some value, which is 0 for all of them - it simply picks a different object where the value is 0 when adding breakpoints).
Unfortunately it's not possible to post any code, because there is way too much of it.

What could cause this kind of behavior?

Edit:
I spent some more time on the problem: It doesn't seem to be related to breakpoints themselves - the "easiest" way to produce different results is the following: When starting the debug process from a different .cpp file of the project the output varies already. When disabling "Build automatically" this doesn't happen anymore. I conclude from that, that even if there are no changes in the code, something is rebuilt.
I also narrowed it down to the class that actually causes the different behavior: It's an implementation of a fibonacci heap.

Comment: Completely inexplicable behavior often (usually?) means some of your code has undefined behavior, but exactly what or where is impossible to guess without code to look at. I would *not* dismiss it though -- strange but innocuous behavior doesn't always stay innocuous.

Comment: Is it meant to select serveral objects and doing it in a different order, or one of several objects and selecting a different one. Either way optimisation is a stand out candidate.

Comment: It is supposed to select one out of many and selects a different one. Optimization is deactivated.

Comment: Is it that you are seeing a different in behavior when you are running under the debugger versus when you are not? Or a difference between running under a debugger versus attaching a debugger?

Comment: @StarPilot: I only tried running under a debugger. But I know that the behavior also changes when switching from debug to run mode and when turning optimizations on, but when trying to create the most simple scenario I narrowed it down to running it in a debugger (the one provided by Eclipse) and switching breakpoints on and off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running on Windows then consider using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/about.html) - [these are the supported platforms](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html). The [Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) tool will run your program (slower) looking at every memory reference to track down use of uninitialized variables.

Memcheck can detect if your program:

- Accesses memory it shouldn't (areas not yet allocated, areas that have been freed, areas past the end of heap blocks, inaccessible areas of the stack).
- Uses uninitialised values in dangerous ways.
- Leaks memory.
- Does bad frees of heap blocks (double frees, mismatched frees).
- Passes overlapping source and destination memory blocks to memcpy() and related functions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Windows, and I already did some work with memory checking tools - they indeed showed some problems, but those were very likely caused by the large amount of reallocations that take place in the program.